# Can I use a specific configuration on my dev environment without changing appsettings.json?

Tags: .net, .net-core

At my company everyone uses Windows. We have some template projects that we use when developing for clients. I dislike working on Windows, so I use a Mac, which causes a problem.

All template projects here have been setup to use LocalDB as SQL server in the `appsettings.json` file. LocalDB is Windows-only, thus I want to use a Docker container with MSSQL instead.

I want to be able to change the connection string without changing the `appsettings.json` file, as it would cause problems with all other developers on the project (who uses Windows).

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connect": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Connect;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

I want to use the following connection string:

```
Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=Connect;User Id=SA;Password=mySecur3!Password
```

Comment: You could add a second appsettings.{environment}.json file which is not included in source control, and use it to override the original connection string, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364665/1398649

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to storing secrets i would recommend to use `secrets.json` as described here: [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows)

`secrets.json` is a file on each local computer that is not checked in.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above .net core support multiple json files. one for each environment,
You can read more here: 
https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fundamentals/environments.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local environment configuration file `appsettings.local.json` which can be added into `.gitignore` to not cause any trouble to others. 
You can read this from a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658455/8714866